# Css style for <ul> with dropdown

Tags: html, css

i have a page that displays a menu and im trying to make and learn to code a responsive layout using @media screen coding.

so i coded the following page;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Header Test</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="font.css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(function(){
  $(window).resize(function(){
    if (window.innerWidth > 850) {
      $("#nav").removeClass('vertical');
    }
  });

  $("#menu").click(function(){
    $("#nav").toggleClass('vertical');
    return false;
  });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="http://www.real-creative.co.uk/new/img/logo-white.png">
    </div>

    <span id="menu"><img src="img/menu-icon.png" width="40" height="40" /></span>

    <div id="navWrap">
      <ul id="nav">
        <li><h1><a href="#">HOME</a></h1></li>
        <li><h1><a href="#">WORK</a></h1></li>
        <li><h1><a href="#">SERVICES</a></h1></li>
        <li><h1><a href="#">ABOUT</a></h1></li>
        <li><h1><a href="#">CONTACT</a></h1></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!--header-->

</body>
</html>
```

what I am trying to achieve is once the page is below 800 pixels wide the button to drop down the navigation appears, I made an image in Photoshop to show what the desired look I wanted, but im unsure on how to style  lists to the way i show in the image.

can anyone please help me out.

URL for current site is:
http://www.real-creative.co.uk/new/

and here is the image;
http://www.real-creative.co.uk/new/viewport.png

appreciate if anyone can help me out.

Comment: You should look into [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com). Implementing that functionality is made very simple. Here's a [YouTube video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpWlaOeGZ_4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, one approach is to use absolute positioning for your div#navWrap, so that it moves when your media query is active.

something like...

```
#navWrap{position:absolute;top:0;left:500px;}

@media all and (max-width: 800px) {

    #navWrap{top:100px;}
    #navWrap ul#nav{border:1px solid #f00;border-radius:10px;width:100px;}
    #navWrap ul#nav li{display:block;border-radius:10px;margin:4px auto;}
}
```

example codepen - http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/pGjco

hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks bro, working on it now i know where to edit and what to look for.